# Ejecución secuencial de Promesas con $.Deferred en Jquery

Tags: jquery, promesas, asincronismo

Tengo este Código, 
Mi pregunta es hay una mejor forma de hacerlo?.

```
    $.when(f_ListarAnioAcademicos()).done(function () {
        $.when(f_ListarCursos()).done(function () {
            $.when(f_ListarHorarioCursos()).done(function () {
                //hacer otra cosa
            }).fail(function () {
                log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarHorarioCursos");
            });
        }).fail(function () {
            log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarCursos ");
        });
    }).fail(function () {
        log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarAnioAcademicos ");
    });
```

Esta quedando feo, ¿hay una forma mejor de hacerlo? ya que cada función depende de la otra.
Ah! algo importante las funciones me retornan `promesas`.

*Ejemplo*:

```
function f_ListarAnioAcademicos() {
    var defered = $.Deferred();
    var strUrl = mstr_Url + "/f_ObtenerAnioAcademicos";
    var aParm = {};
    $.get(strUrl, aParm).done(function (data) {
        defered.resolve();
    }).fail(function (data) {
        defered.reject()
    });
    return defered.promise();
}
```

Gracias..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías sacar provecho del patrón [`encadenando promesas`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneCallbacks-failCallbacks-progressCallbacks) (en ingles `chaining promises`):

> Las `callbacks` se ejecutan en el orden en que se agregaron. Dado que `deferred.then` devuelve una `Promise`, otros métodos del objeto `Promise` pueden ser encadenados a éste, incluyendo métodos `.then()` adicionales.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
f_ListarAnioAcademicos()
  .then(f_ListarCursos, function() {
    log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarAnioAcademicos ");
  })
  .then(f_ListarHorarioCursos, function() {
    log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarCursos ");
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    // En este caso "res" es igual a lo devuelto por "f_ListarHorarioCursos"
    console.log(res);
    
    //hacer otra cosa 
  }, function() {
    log.info("Ocurrio un error no ejecuta: f_ListarHorarioCursos");
  });

/////////////////

function f_ListarAnioAcademicos() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve('Exito f_ListarAnioAcademicos');
  }, 500);
  return dfd.promise();
}

function f_ListarCursos(res) {
  // En este caso "res" es igual a lo devuelto por "f_ListarAnioAcademicos"
  console.log(res);
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve('Exito f_ListarCursos');
  }, 500);
  return dfd.promise();
}

function f_ListarHorarioCursos(res) {
  // En este caso "res" es igual a lo devuelto por "f_ListarCursos"
  console.log(res);
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve('Exito f_ListarHorarioCursos');
  }, 500);
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**PD**: Tambíen se puede hacer con `.done() y fail()`

Comment: Gracias... Tengo curiosidad. ¿Como se haría con `done()` y el `fail()`?

Comment: @VitmarAliaga, aquí viene la parte donde tu intentas resolverlo por tu cuenta y si tienes problemas, nos lo haces saber  ;)